# htaccesss redirect / google webmaster's "change of address"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-search-console

so I have this in my .htaccess:

`Redirect / http://blabla.net/`

(which redirects all pages from my old domain, blabla.com, to my new domain - blabla.net)

I also wanted to use "change of address" from the google webmater tools, but it tells me that my old site is not verified (even though it is), and that's because it gets redirected to the new site :)

so how can ignore a single request from .htaccess, like this one:

`http://blabla.com/google4befdedcf3629c8a.html`

(this should not be redirected to blabla.net/google ...)

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to check for that specific request.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/google4befdedcf3629c8a.html
```

Also, I would encourage you to update your `Redirect` to respond with a 301 if this is a permanent redirection (the default is 302).

```
Redirect 301 / http://blabla.net/
```

#### UPDATE

`RewriteCond` uses `mod_rewrite`, whereas `Redirect` is `mod_alias`. So you can't mix and match. I should have explicitly provided the full change if you decide to use `RewriteCond`. **Note** that the `RewriteEngine` does incur overhead. So this may not be the ideal solution.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/google4befdedcf3629c8a.html
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://blabla.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's the right spot. Note that if you are not using `mod_rewrite`, you can't use `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Just temporarily remove the redirect from htaccess while Google verifies your site, then re-instate the redirect. It should only take about a minute.</s>

Edit: Nevermind, Google will periodically check, and will revoke access if the verification vanishes.

Comment: yes I did that, but doesn't Google need that verification thing all the time? I see that it verifies it periodically..

Comment: Although a quick solution, this would not be ideal for a live site.